# django requests get mixed up?

Tags: python, django, apache

I have 3 django projects with different settings, 2 under the subdomains `parents.abc.com,teachers.abc.com and abc.com.` They all come under a shared apache instance. Here is my httpd configuration file:

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog /home/user/logs/user/access_django.log combined
ErrorLog /home/user/logs/user/error_django.log
KeepAlive Off
Listen 37049
MaxSpareThreads 3
MinSpareThreads 1
ServerLimit 1
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ThreadsPerChild 5
WSGIDaemonProcess django processes=5 python-path=/home/user/webapps/django:/home/user/webapps/django/lib/python2.6 threads=1
WSGIPythonPath /home/user/webapps/django:/home/user/webapps/django/lib/python2.6
NameVirtualHost *:37049

<VirtualHost *:37049>
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/webapps/django/abc.wsgi
        ServerName abc.com
        ServerAlias abc.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:37049>
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/webapps/django/parents.wsgi
        ServerAlias parents.abc.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:37049>
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/webapps/django/teachers.wsgi
        ServerAlias teachers.abc.com
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem comes (after a restart) if I visit parents.abc.com, followed by teachers.abc.com (or vice versa), I will encounter url error in the second because it seems like it is referencing the urls.py for the first project. i.e teachers.abc.com is looking at the settings file for parents.abc.com (vice versa).

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: @Tom-Gruner is right, and you might also want to checkout http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango and read it carefully

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the server name in each vhost

Add in:

```
ServerName parents.abc.com
```

and:

```
ServerName teachers.abc.com
```

ServerAlias, as far as I know, by itself is not enough to define a name based virtual host.